# MySql 5.7 master-master (restore a master by replication vs dump)

Tags: mysql, master-master-replication

We have MySql 5.7 running in Centos 7 in cloud environment.
We have the master-master working properly. One master gets the writes which replicates to the other master. The second master is a hot standby in case the 1st master dies.

Currently we need to rebuild the masters on a somewhat regular basis. We are doing this by restoring from mysql backups and then adding the new master into the replication.

We would like to avoid using the mysql backups for replacing masters. 
We would like to turn off a Master, Build a new Master, configure the masters and then allow the Master (that we did not replace) to populate the Master (that we replaced).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please explain the _purpose_ of regular "rebuilding".

Comment: Sorry for my delay. We rebuild these regularly just means we need an automated means to sync. We do not want to have to do a backup and restore (though this can be automated). We want to be able to rebuild a machine (terminate it and stand up a new one, configure it) and have it sync with the other master that is still up. So we will always have 1 master up at all times.

Comment: Rebuilding involves first loading a not-too-old dump, then letting Replication "catch up".  I don't think there is a single-step way to rebuild a second Master or Slave.

Comment: Ok. I was thinking I could take a Master (a slave) without any dump on it. Then tell it to get the logs of the Running Master from its very first record.

Comment: True, if you save _all_ the binlogs, you can reload from that.  But it will be slower and sloower and slooower as the binlogs grow.

Comment: Thanks Rick. Will restore from backup or snapshots and then sync.